# Difference between hash tables and random access tables

Tags: data-structures

What is the difference between Hash tables and random access tables. I feel that they are similar , but wanted to find out the exact differences, Googling did not help me much.

Comment: What is "random access table"? A plain array or arraylist or What?

Comment: @hyde: just wanted to ask the same:-)

Comment: If this question is important to you, I suggest take your time and rewrite it as detailed as you can.

Comment: I think in programming context, "table" implies "random access". So your question becomes something like: what is hash table and what other kinds of tables there are? Which is hopelessly broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general Hash Tables are there to be able to map things like various entities to other entities. Depending on programming language it may be mapping tuples to strings, strings to objects, strings to strings and so on - infinite possibilities.

Regular arrays let you address entities using integer index:

> array[index] ==> string for example

On the contrary hash maps aka hash tables aka dictionaries aka associative arrays aka hashes etc let you - among other possibilities - map a string to integer for example:

> hash_map['Bill'] => 23 etc

For basic understanding go to:

- [wiki hash tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)
- [Python dicts](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)
- [PHP arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

For more advanced understanding I recommend these 2 books:

- ['Algorithms' by Sadgewick](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032157351X)
- ['Data Structures and Algorithms' by Drozdek](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00E28TS3G)

Answer (score 0):

A hash table (aka hash map, or associative array or dictionary or just a hash) is a specific type of random access data structure.

A Hash Table is "random access" because it allows direct, "indexed" access to individual members in constant time. An Array may also be considered a random access data structure, because you can fetch an individual element by its index.

In contrast, a linked list is not a random access data structure, because you need to iterate through its members to find a specific element.